# How can I redirect in django middleware? global name 'view' is not defined

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-middleware

Django newbie here, need help on basic middleware to redirect to another view if a certain model field is empty.

I am creating a terms of agreement page that users must get redirected to right after they signup to the platform if their filed_terms field on their Profile model is empty.

I am using middleware for this. However I am unable to get this to work. This is my middleware class:

```
class TermsMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.user.profile.filled_terms is None:
            return redirect(reverse(terms))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
global name 'terms' is not defined
```

I also have the url matcher that works perfectly when I navigate to it manually:

```
url(r'^terms/', 'my_app.views.terms')
```

I have a terms.html template and a terms view in my views.py file that is working perfectly in all other respects. I have also added it to the settings middleware requirements to make sure it loads.

Do I have to import something from views or url dispatcher into my middleware file? If so what would that be? I have been at this for a while an cannot find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` function takes `url` name instead on the regex. So you need to add `name` on your `url` configuration. Here is the example.

```
url(r'^terms/', 'my_app.views.terms', name='terms')
```

Add this in your `views.py`

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

And you need to fix your reverse function into.

```
return redirect(reverse('terms'))
```

Python interpret your `terms` as a variable and you have no variable named `terms` while you need to put string on [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: because when you got to the url manually, it will use your regex on url, while `reverse` will use `name`. You can make your code work by removing the `reverse` into `return redirect('terms') `

Comment: When I try your solution I just get perpetually redirected to terms. I think its a loop to terms that wont stop.

Comment: If that is the case, I think the problem is on another context. The point is that the routing is already works. Feel free to submit another question.

Comment: It's `from django.urls import reverse` instead of `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` now.